# Prestashop: Send mail on return status change

Tags: email, return, prestashop, status, orders

Is there any way to configure Prestashop to send an email when the return status of an order changes?

I've seen that it is possible to indicate whether to send a mail or not in the order status changes, but couldn't find that option for the return status changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code for sending mail in the hook `actionObjectOrderReturnUpdateAfter`. When updating the order return status, this hook is called.

```
public function hookActionObjectOrderReturnUpdateAfter()
{
    // send mail code
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where to find that hook?

Comment: Action hooks may not be found easily but you can check it in database. Try registering this hook and using it. If it doesn't work you can check /controllers/admin/AdminStatusesController.php from where default functionality of changing status runs.